# Shift the file while writing?

Tags: java, indexing, byte, filewriter

Is it possible to shift the contents of a file while writing to it using FileWriter?
I need to write data constants to the head of the file and if I do that it overwrites the file.
What technique should I use to do this or should I make make copies of the file (with the new data on top) on every file write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite certain bytes of the file and not others, you can use seek and write to do so. If you want to change the content of every byte in the file (by, for example, adding a single byte to the beginning of the file) then you need to write a new file and potentially rename it after you've done writing it.

Think of the answer to the question "what will be the contents of the byte at offset x after I'm done?". If, for a large percent of the possible values of x the answer is "not what it used to be" then you need a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than contending ourselves with the question "what will be the contents of the byte at offset x after I'm done?", lets change the mindset and ask why can't the file system or perhaps the hard disk firmware do : a) provide another mode of accessing the file [let's say, inline] b) increase the length of the file by the number of bytes added at the front or in the middle or even at the end c) move each byte that starts from the crossection by the newcontent.length positions

It would be easier and faster to handle these operations at the disk firmware or file system implementation level rather than leaving that job to the application developer. I hope file system writers or hard disk vendors would offer such feature soon.

Regards,
Samba